# Display inline-block (vertical center) not working - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, display

I am using bootstrap to create a layout however, I can't seem to understand why display:inline-block with vertical-align: middle isn't working.

I would prefer not to use position absolute.

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yheep9hh/**

Any help would be appreciated

**HTML:**
Currently using bootstrap to create the layout (navbar, etc)

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">hello</a></div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="active" href="/Home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Website Design">Website Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Tech Support">Tech Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Data Security">Data Security</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Networking">Networking</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper bgImage">
        <div class="indexWelcome">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1 class="text-center">Welcome To Amparo Tech</h1>
                    <h3 class="text-center">How Can We Help You?</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row input-fixedWidth">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form class="homeForm" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2 col-md-8">
                                <input class="homeFormEmail" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2 col-md-8">
                                <input class="homeFormPostcode" type="text" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2 col-md-8">
                                <textarea class="homeFormMessage" name="message" placeholder="Your Message or Tech Issue"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-left pull-left">
                    <p>name</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right pull-right">
                    <p>number</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <p>address</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

**CSS:**
Custom CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, 
body {
  height:100%;
}

h1, 
h2, 
h3, 
h4, 
h5, 
h6 {
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height:calc(100% - 82px);
  margin: 0 auto -10px;
}

.footer, .push {
  height: 10px;
}

.navbar {
  margin:0;
  height:52px;
}

input, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.input-fixedWidth {
  max-width:750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.formWrapper {
  position:relative;
}


.indexWelcome {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}


.navbar-transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.homeFormEmail {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.homeFormEmail, 
.homeFormPostcode, 
.homeFormMessage {
  text-indent: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size:14px;
}

.homeFormEmail, 
.homeFormPostcode {
  height:40px;
}

.homeFormMessage {
  height: 80px;
  padding-top:10px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical-align:middle; works well with display:table-cell; that is if the parent div is display:table;

Answer (score 0):

To display a `<div>` block vertically aligned in the middle, you need to use display `table` and `table-cell` to the parent and child respectively.

Have a look at the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7totjt2p/1/)** (jsFiddle)

Just like:

```
/* Parent */
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

/* Child */
.indexWelcome {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

since css flexbox is [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) almost everywhere these days i would use it, since it makes vertical alignment very easy:

```
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

**demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/7totjt2p/2/